# How to move the image to the right bottom corner of the webpage

Tags: html, css

I have a small web-page. My requirement is to make the image as a link and that image should be place in right bottom corner of my webpage. i tried but width property is not working.

```css
input.right-corner {
  width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  position:fixed;
  right:0px;
  bottom:0px;

}
```

```html
<div class="corner">
  <input type="image" src="images/Happiest_Minds_New_Logo.jpg" class="right-corner"> 
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can see that the image is the right bottom of the page you can add margins for styles propses if you want .and just change the width property and it will change to the width you want
** you can change the href of the link to the link you want to acess when clicking to the image
*** you can delete the div container because i only use it to show you the position of the element

```css
    .container {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border:1px solid black;
    }
    .corner {
    position:relative;
    margin-top:auto;
    width:auto;
    height:200px;}
    a{
    width:20px;
    height:10px;
    }
    .right-corner{
     position:absolute;
       width:20px;
       height:10px;
       right:0px;
       bottom:0px;
    }
```

```html
 <div class='container'>
<div class="corner">
 <a href='https://i.ibb.co/ZYW3VTp/brown-brim.png'><img src='https://i.ibb.co/ZYW3VTp/brown-brim.png' alt='img' class='right-corner'></a>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Sorry this is not working. Will share my whole code. please have a look at it.

Comment: i changed the code you can see now hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add:

```
text-align: left;
```

This should be your code:

```
input.right-corner {
  width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  position:fixed;
  right:0px;
  bottom:0px;
 text-align: left;
} 
<div class="corner">
  <input type="image" src="images/Happiest_Minds_New_Logo.jpg" class="right-corner"> 
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using position**

Position fixed is relative to the containing block. So you'll need a parent, that wraps the page, in order to put the image where you want.

```
.corner {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
}

.right-corner{
  width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  position:fixed;
  right:0px;
  bottom:0px;
 }
```

**Using flexbox**

```
.corner{
  display:flex;
  position:aboslute;
  justify-content:flex-end;
  align-items:flex-end;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

This normally works. But it might not be the best depending on your page structure.